# Laravel 3.x working with Forms and drop down

Tags: php, laravel

Hy all, im working with Forms in laravel and i have problem with dropdown(select).

In my controller i have this:

```
public function get_edit($id) {
    $select = array('A' => 'something1', 'B' => 'something2', 'C' => 'something3');
    $this->data['id'] = $id;
    $this->data['options'] = $select;

    return View::make('blabla::folder.edit', $this->data);
}
```

And in that view(among others forms input) i have this line:

```
{{ Form::select('something', $options) }}
```

Problem is that when i select some option from dropdown in the view, for example "something1" i expected to get back "something1" but i get "A".

For example i need to populate some table with value from dropdown, 
which is demonstrated on the below picture, in cell where i'm expecting to get "something1" i get "A".

Fetching data with:

```
    $input = Input::get('something');
```

Picture: http://pokit.org/get/?f183e32124e80b1f37804bbb576ccc0a.jpg

Any suggestion(beside inverting key/value)?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you need the A, B and C values? A dropdown form always returns the "value" field from the <option> tags, which are the keys in the array you provide. If you want the displayed value in the drop down to be the value that is returned in Input::get(), then you need to use the same value for both the key and value in the array, 'something1' => 'something1'.

Comment: But what if i have value which is "something something1", i dont want white space in key.

Comment: If the value you want coming back after the form is submitted should contain that whitespace, then that whitespace has to be in the value attribute of the option tag, that's just how 'select' and 'option' tags work in HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your array from

```
array('A' => 'something1', 'B' => 'something2', 'C' => 'something3');
```

to

```
array('something1' => 'something1', 'something2' => 'something2', 'something3' => 'something3');
```

Because value is passed when you select an item from the `select` and in your `select` you have values `A`, `B` and `C`.